# netsuite suiteScipt 2.0 Search: is there a way to filter by nested object keys?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Trying to write a restlet in netsuite and filter by a nested key, however I can't seem to crack it
`

`````
 var f1 = search.createFilter({
            name: 'salesrep.id',
            operator: search.Operator.IS,
            values: '77'
});
        var filter;
        var id;
        if(context.closerId) {
            filter = 'custentity_bb_sales_rep_employee'; 
            id = context.closerId;
        } else if (context.setterId)        {
            filter = 'custentity_ss_setter_employee';
            id = context.setterId;
        }
      var mySearch = search.create({
        type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
        columns: ['entityid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'salesrep', 'custentity_ss_setter_employee', 'custentity_bb_sales_rep_employee', 'custentity_bb_home_owner_phone', 'custentity_bb_install_address_1_text', 'custentity_bb_install_city_text', 'custentity_bb_install_state', 'custentity_bb_install_zip_code_text' ],
        filters: [f1],

    });````

heres the code I'm trying and yet its not working, I'm wondering if there even is a way to filtter by salesrep.id

I've tried pretty much everything in the documentation, not sure where to go from here
`````

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to use arbitrary 'nested properties' in the filters.
But, NetSuite supports the concept of a search join.
From my experience, you need to use NetSuite records browser, to see which joins are available on a particular record type and what they refer to (which record), then you can use some (not every) property of the referred record's.

E.g. you want to find all the cusomer records, which have their salesrep referred record's id as '77'.

So you open the NetSuite records browser: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/customer.html

And see which joins does it support:

[image: NetSuite records browser screenshot]

Indeed, it does support the salesrep join and it refers to the Employee record type. So you go to the Employee https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/employee.html to find which Search Filters it supports, and you use those filters (from the 'joined' record). You'll see that there is no 'id' search filter, but instead there is 'internalid', this must be what you need:

[image: Employee record page from NetSuite records browser]

So this piece of code (the original one):

```
//this is wrong:
var f1 = search.createFilter({
    name: 'salesrep.id',
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: '77'
});
```

must be (**also please not the array literal** in the values property, I'm not sure if a string, as in your original example will work)

```
var f1 = search.createFilter({
    name: 'internalid',
    join: 'salesrep',
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: ['77']
});
```

I'm not sure if your code will work, since it's a bit messy, but the filter should be correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "nested object keys", but there is a simple solution for your example of filtering by 'salesrep.id' - you simply specify it as 'salesrep'.

```
search.createFilter({
    name: 'salesrep',
    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
    values: '77'
})
```

Note also that for List/Record (select/dropdown) fields you should use the ANYOF operator rather than IS.

Further comments: if by "nested object keys" you are referring to values that come from record joins, then you can use the `join` property of the `search.createFilter(options)` options parameter.  For example, if you wanted to use the sales rep's name instead of internal id, you could do:

```
search.createFilter({
    join: 'salesrep',
    name: 'entityid',
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: 'Tom Sawyer'  //Put the sales rep's name here
})
```